# Woocommerce Tax not working properlytax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to allow discount or add tax for shipping for specific states only. Example: tax rate is applicable only in California(US) 9 percent, and any other country or states should zero tax, but doesn't work. All country and states appear with 9 percent tax. 
Is this a bug or there is something I am missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found A solution. The checkout.js does not work since I forgot to include this

```
  get_footer()
```

in my custom template.